# Kubernetes Deployment restartPolicy alternatives

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Deployment configuration that keeps a certain amount of Pods alive. However due to some strange circumstances these Pods fail the readiness probes sometimes and do not recover after a restart thus requiring me to manually delete the Pod from the Replica Set.

A solution to this would be to set the Pod restartPolicy to Never but that is actually not supported https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24725.

My question is what alternatives are there to make it so that if a Pod has failed it's readiness probe then the Pod would be deleted.

Comment: What are the strange circumstances? What you are saying shouldn't be the case.

Comment: The DNS stops resolving inside of a Pod thus making it completely dead. For some reason this only recovers after deleting the Pod but restarts don't seem to affect it.

Comment: Could you please provide yaml  files for the pods with the readiness probe, and output of the command `kubectl describe pod`?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the liveness probe to make it fail whenever the readiness probe fails. This would kill the pod, and start a new one.